# @metamask/detect-provider: Unable to detect window.ethereum

Tags: web3js, metamask, web3-providers

I want to set web3 to Metamask. As mentioned in [Metamask document](https://docs.metamask.io/guide/ethereum-provider.html#table-of-contents) and [npmjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@metamask/detect-provider), i took a use `@metamask/detect-provider`. My problem is when i approach `window.ethereum`. I have a UI, JS file, and some contracts. My `app.js` code is below. Whenever my http request is `/send-to-ipfs` i approach this message in console:

```
@metamask/detect-provider: Unable to detect window.ethereum.
Please install MetaMask!
```

Please check my `app.js` code and comment about am i coding correct to set `Metamask` as web3 provider or not, and in that case guide me to correct code.

app.js:

```
const fs = require("fs");
const ipfsClient = require('ipfs-http-client');
const Hash = require('ipfs-only-hash')
const contract=require("truffle-contract");
const Web3 = require("web3");
const Window = require('window');
const window = new Window();
const detectEthereumProvider=require('@metamask/detect-provider');
const solc=require("solc");
const express=require('express');
const app=express();
const bodyParser=require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.use(express.static('E:/Test'));
app.set('view engine',"pug");
app.set('views','./views');


app.post('/send-to-ipfs', async function(q,r){
    const node= ipfsClient({ host: 'localhost', port: '5001', protocol: 'http' });
    const data=q.body.KeyPad;
    let result=await Hash.of(data)
    node.add(data);
    const provider=await detectEthereumProvider();
    if (provider) {
        startApp(provider); // initialize your app
    } else {
          console.log('Please install MetaMask!');
    }
    r.render('IPFSconnection2.jade',{key: data, cid:result});
});
... here is some code that are not my peoblem ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem here is that you are trying to retrieve the Metamask provider from the server side, whereas Metamask is a browser extension and therefore, you should do so from the **client side**.

Answer (score 0):

Update your metamask extension. it resolves my same issue

Comment: I did but with no results.